# How to wrap text UILabel Xcode with Storyboard settings

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I am unable to wrap text using Xcode 9.2 Storyboarding.

This screen shot is a single UILabel, vertically and horizontally center in a view, no other code at all:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my Storyboard settings, I have set `Lines = 0` and `Line Break = Word Wrap`

[image]

Comment: You need to add `left` and `rigth` constraints or a `width` constraint at least

Comment: Can you share screenshot for size inspector of label ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `leading` and `trailing` constraint to your label

[image]

Or you can add a width constraint relative to the superview `width`

[image]

Comment: This is not centered vertically (you add only top constraint)

Comment: the issue is related to leak of leading and trailing constraints the OP know how add a center vertically constraint as I think @DominikBucher

Comment: So why the last constraint is even in your answer?

Comment: Its an screenshot @DominikBucher mi answer is "Or you can add a width constraint relative to the superview width" as you can read

Comment: Anyway I had updated my second screenshot, by the way is not a good practice disqualify others answer only because you think that your answer is the best answer, I think is the OP who can judge that @DominikBucher, best regards

Comment: Why do you think that I am the downvoter? @DominikBucher but anyway I can tell you nobody here explain why downvote your answer this is SO democracy

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ReinierMelian, how do I add a Proportional Width to the SuperView? Cannot seem to figure that out in Xcode 9

Answer (score 1):

Xcode does exactly what it is told to do. What do you expect when you center something vertically and horizontally? It should be centered, only centered. Lines set to 0 is correct approach.

The thing you are missing in here is trailing and leading to the superview/safe areas. And adding Greater than constraints from top and bottom. Line breaks don't do a thing unless you set the size. So you have to either set height and width (Really do not do this...) Or set trailing and leading, in this case you can delete the horizontal center because it will be handled by the 2 constraints (you need to set them to same value)

So the solution:

1. Add equal constraints from sides (leading, trailing)
2. Add greater than constraints from top and bottom (but keep the vertical center constraint)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add some constraints to your label so it wraps the text. Remember to set the correct width, this width won't change.

If you just have your label, the easiest way to do this is to click on the button "Resolve auto layout issues" and then "Add missing constraints" as you can see on the image:

[Auto add constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaMys.png)

If there are more elements on your screen, then I recommend you to take a look on SnapKit [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/blob/develop/README.md) (a DSL to make Auto Layout easy on both iOS and OS X).

Comment: Why to use for such simple layout SnapKit? :D What do you achieve by using unreliable frameworks and don't learn a single thing?

Comment: That's why I wrote "If there are more elements on your screen", it is clearly stated that this approach wouldn't be for the simple layout. There are many ways to add constraints, I just wanted to share one of the tools I use, if you  do it in a different way that's ok.